# Can't set response code to 200 in PHP

Tags: php, http-headers, http-status-codes

I'm trying to set the response code in a PHP script to 200.  Later I set a `Location` header, which sets it to 302.  According to the documentation:

> Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also
>   returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or
>   a 3xx status code has already been set.

Is there no way to set the header to 200 and not have the `location` header override it? I've tried setting the response code header after the location header, but that doesn't work (presumably because the location header has already been sent along with the body including the "Found" HTML bit).

I could use 201 as the response code, since the application accecssing the script only checks for any 2xx code.  However, according to the HTTP 1.1 spec:

> The origin server MUST create the resource before returning the 201 status code.

But I'm not creating anything.  Is that a problem, or can I get away with it?

Comment: Why 200 if you're redirecting?

Comment: It's a bit of a confusing reason, but the same script is called from two places, one that requires a 200 response code, and one that needs the location... although I could probably have one of those places send some other parameter to determine whether the Location: header should be sent or not.  Whoops, answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an answer to my particular problem.  My original problem was that one place needed the `redirect` header and another place needed the `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` header, so I was able to use one or the other depending on the source.

However, after trying the 201 option, that didn't work either, (still 302) so I don't know if that's a bug or if I was doing it wrong or what.

Comment: Sir, I have detailed why it did not work in my answer: it *should* not work since status 200 is invalid in conjunction with a `location` redirect. It is contrary to the standard, so it is good that it didn't work :)

Comment: But why didn't the 201 work, which is documented that it should work correctly but didn't?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html, 201 (as you discuss in your OP) is a different case. The php docs even mention this code (http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) - 201 means that your request was successfully processed and implies that a new URI was created as a result of your request. The URI can be passed with the status, but it is not considered a "call to action" for the user agent - the agent is not expected to visit the given URI. Conversely, a 3xx code is an explicit instruction to the user agent.

Comment: Well, I don't need the user agent to actually DO anything, I just need the response code 201 to be used, but in every case, using the Location: header cause the 302 response to show up, even though I explicitly set it to 201 before, and after, and even during the header("Location:...") call

Comment: What is your PHP version? This was a bug in a past version (4.3.3-RC3), but was corrected. I just made a test document, and if I do this it works exactly as expected: `header('HTTP/1.1 201 Created'); header("Location: http://www.php.net/");` - I get a blank document with the header `201 Created` and a `location` of `http://www.php.net/`

Comment: Ooops, see edit to previous comment.  Try to make a blank document with just those two lines, see what your result is.

Answer (score 2):

According to [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), a 200 status code WITH a redirect is not valid (see *10.3 Redirection 3xx*). When redirecting, only a 3xx code is valid.

You can continue to send an arbitrary 2xx code if it is getting the job done, but this would be outside the standard and theoretically not reliable across all user agents.

Comment: Not to mention that search engines might tag the page invalid and stop indexing it.

Comment: This isn't a page that we worry about being searchable at all.

Comment: It is valid however when using CGI, because it instructs the web server to do an internal redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The "Location: " argument in `header()` is intended for a redirect. A redirect is an instruction for the HTTP requester (i.e. the user-agent) to send a new request to the server with the information given in "Location".

Setting a status code with 200 at any time therefore is an error and has to be disregarded; which should default to 302.

If you don't want to redirect then simply don't set the location!